# Selected Value is not binding in drownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my code service field is not binding but Location field is binding

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult EditServicesToProvider(string RefServiceID, string LocationID)
            {
                if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    return new RedirectResult(Utility.Config("RedirectPath"));
                if (Request.Cookies["hnuserId"] != null)
                {
                    Session["UserID"] = Request.Cookies["hnuserId"];
                }
                ServicesManager asm = RankedServices.Business.Provider.ServicesCriteria.GetProviderServiceDetails(RefServiceID);

                List<RankedServices.Entities.Admin.Services> MS = RankedServices.Business.AdminBiz.AdminBLL.LoadMasterServices();
                ViewBag.Services = new SelectList(MS, "ServiceID", "ServiceName");

                List<RankedServices.Entities.Admin.Location> ML = RankedServices.Business.AdminBiz.AdminBLL.LoadMasterLocation();
                ViewBag.Locations = new SelectList(ML, "LocationID", "LocationName");

                List<RankedServices.Entities.Admin.SubLocation> Sublocationlist = asm.lstSubLocations.ToList(); //RankedServices.Business.Provider.ServicesCriteria.LodSubLocation(LocationID);
                ViewBag.SubLocations = new MultiSelectList((Sublocationlist).AsEnumerable(), "SubLocationID", "SubLocationName");


                return View(asm);
            }
```

BAL code for getting dropdown for services

```
public static List<Services> LoadMasterServices()
    {
        List<Services> Sr = new List<Services>();
        DataTable _dt = AdminDAL.LoadMasterServices();
        foreach (DataRow _dr in _dt.Rows)
        {
            Services Serv = new Services();
            Serv.ServiceID = int.Parse(_dr[0].ToString());
            Serv.ServiceName = _dr[1].ToString();
            Sr.Add(Serv);
        }
        return Sr;
    }
```

BAL code for getting dropdown for Location and it is binding:

```
public static List<Location> LoadMasterLocation()
{
    List<Location> Loc = new List<Location>();
    DataTable _dt = AdminDAL.LoadMasterLocation();
    foreach (DataRow _dr in _dt.Rows)
    {
        Location lc = new Location();
        lc.LocationID = int.Parse(_dr[0].ToString());
        lc.LocationName = _dr[1].ToString();
        Loc.Add(lc);
    }
    return Loc;
}
```

View:

Location drop down is working and it is also binding

```
@Html.DropDownList("LocationID", ViewBag.Locations as SelectList, "Select Location", new { @class ="form-control location_select" })
```

Servicedrop down is working and but selected values is not binding

```
@Html.DropDownList("ServiceID", ViewBag.Services as SelectList, "Select Service", new { @class ="form-control"})
```

Comment: If `ServiceID` is a property in your model (not a field) and its value is set  in the GET method and matches the value of one of your options, then it will be bound correctly (and use the strong typed `DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceID, ....)` not `DropDownList("ServiceID", ...)`)

Comment: I have used DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceID, ....) and the selected values is available in the dropdown but it is not binding

Comment: And LocationID is binding

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "field is not binding". Does the Services dropdown remain empty (no items)? Does it have items, but selected item is incorrect / always the same initially? Does the Action method not receive the selected item?

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, Action method parameter names should match Form field names.

The Action method expects `string RefServiceID`, change it to `string ServiceID` instead.

Comment: But iam getting data from RefServiceID after that only iam showing that data in edit page

Comment: RefServiceID  and ServiceID both are different